# Unable to pass data between multiple jsp pages

Tags: jsp

Trying to pass data (values) between JSP pages.  Want to display the same name and age input by the user in the HTML code.

My program has 3 files.  Flow is

```
 inputname.html -> printname.jsp -> printclass.jsp
```

1. inputname.html: user inputs their name and age
2. printname.jsp : displays the name and age and input their qualification
3. printclass.jsp : display ALL three: name, age and qualification.

Problem is I cannot get proper values of name and age in `printclass.jsp`; values are `null`.

Relevant code from `printname.jsp`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>

<%  String Name=request.getParameter("name");%> 
<%  String Age=request.getParameter("age");%>   

<h1 >
welcome
<%= Name%>,
<%= Age %>
</h1>
 <br><br>

 <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8090/htmltojsp1/printclass.jsp">


  <% request.setAttribute("name",Name) ; %>
  <% request.setAttribute("age",Age) ; %>


  <h3>choose a Class</h3><p>
  <select name="class" size="1">
     <option>School
     <option>College
     <option>bsc
      <option>mca 
  </select>
  <br> <br>
  <center>
    <input type="SUBMIT">
  </center>
  </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Relevant code from `printclass.jsp`:

```
<html>

<body>
<h1 >

<%  String Name=request.getParameter("name");%> 
<%  String Age=request.getParameter("age");%>   

<h1 >
welcome
<%= Name%>,
<%= Age %>
</h1>
 <br><br>

<br><br>
<h2>you are in 
<%= request.getParameter("class")%>
 <h2>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use request.setAttribute those will only be available on the current JSP page - the request on your next page will be set to what you have in your form (or params in your URL). Instead you can use a hidden input element inside your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<%= Name %>" />
```

Btw. you should use lowercase on your attribute names. (So use name instead of Name).

Comment: can you please reccomond  some good link for JSp - Servlet Tutorial.

Comment: I don't have any particular tutorials on JSP I can recommend - there are some free books though if you google for it. You might also want to look into JSTL, IBM has a nice guide here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211/index.html